# Basic sympy problem in anaconda

Tags: anaconda

I have enabled sympy on Anaconda to use it to solve basic linear equations, but whenever I try to type something up it gives me an error when defining the variables:

```
from sympy import *
x,y=symbols(’x,y’);
solution=solve((4*x-3*y-17,7*x+5*y-11),x,y);
P=(solution[x],solution[y]);
print(P);
```

This code gives me this error message:

```
  x,y=symbols(’x,y’);
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

Does anyone know how I could fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the `’` to `"` it works just fine, see:

```
from sympy import *
x,y=symbols("x,y");
solution=solve((4*x-3*y-17,7*x+5*y-11),x,y);
P=(solution[x],solution[y]);

print(P)
(118/41, -75/41)
```